# How to jump back to the last position of the cursor in emacs?

Tags: emacs

In emacs, when i am editing a program, and miss-input some command and make the cursor jump to somewhere in other files. Is there a short-cut key or command to jump back to the last location of the cursor?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I believe what you are searching for is `pop-global-mark`, usually bound to <kbd>C-x C-@</kbd> and <kbd>C-x C-SPC</kbd>.

The global mark ring is updated automatically on many occasions such as buffer switching, accidental or otherwise.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the command previous-buffer which in my version (GNU Emacs 23.2.1) is bound to `C-x left-arrow` by default.

Just type Meta-x describe-key C-x left for further information

There is also [winner-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode) that binds `C-c left arrow` to winner-undo which in short allows you to undo any change done to your windows.

Answer (score 9):

In Spacemacs and Doom Emacs, `C-o` is bound to `evil-jump-backward`

**GitHub Repositories**

- [syl20bnr/spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs)
- [doomemacs/doomemacs](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs)